# spring starter rest class not found hibernateexception

Tags: spring-boot

I downloaded the latest released Spring Toolkit - 3.8.1 Release.
I installed the starter "Import Spring Getting Started Content" -> "Accessing Data Rest"

I then tried to run "Complete" in a tomcat server and separately as a java application. In both cases it crashed. Most of the stack trace is omitted below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
... 65 common frames omitted
```

Is there any fix?

Also, there is no Hello controller and the web site (https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/) does not refer to creating such a thing.

Is it just completely broken?

Comment: The problem persists on my first computer. I have done this on three different computers: two windows 10, one windows 7: One one of the windows 10 computers, even with a fresh STS install in a new directory, this exception persists. This is both with the spring starter rest project and another project installed from github that works fine in the other two installs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I haven't discovered the ultimate cause, but I have solved the problem.

The computer where this wasn't working had had older versions of eclipse installed in the past, e.g. gallileo. The .eclipse directory dated from April 2013.

Completely removing the .eclipse and reinstalling STS caused STS to work fine. It is also important to install eclipse/STS outside of Windows protected directories like "Program Files" since we don't want to run eclipse as an administrator and Eclipse likes to write files in its installation directory.